# Efficient Way to take first n sorted elements in Spark Partitions

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, partition

I have created an RDD from array in Spark. I want to take n smallest elements from on each partition.  I have sorted iterator at each partition every time and take first n elements and replaces them with elements of arr1. The way i have done is

```
 var arr = (1 to 50000).toArray
 val n = 50
 val iterations = 100  
 val r = new Random() 
 val arr1 = Array.fill(n)(r.nextInt(10)) 

 val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr,3)
 rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{(index , it) =>  
 it=it.sortWith(_<_)

  for(i<- 0 until n){
   it(i) = arr1(i)   
  }
  it
 }
```

I want to ask is there any efficient way to perform same task in Scala

Comment: val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr,3)   do you not mean arr1 ?

Comment: mapPartitions would also be fine

Comment: Not convinced on the code

Comment: It is unclear and one can see it will not run

Comment: @thebluephantom yes arr1 not arr.

Comment: change but it does not run

Answer (score 1):

```
rdd.sortBy(x=>x)
.foreachPartition(y=>println(y.take(n).toList))
```

Replace println with your use case

Comment: This code will sort whole RDD first than will take n elements on each partition and will print out them

Comment: If data is large in partition then it may throw OOM if sorting is implemented into scala seq/Array etc... foreachPartition returns Iterator which doesn't have sort.. converting it to Seq and then sorting is possible but if data is large OOM is possible